# Permutação entre dois vetores

Tags: java

Estou estudando algumas técnicas de algoritmos e me deparei com um problema que estou empacado, eu preciso fazer todas as possibilidades de permutação entre dois vetores. Por exemplo:

[1,2,3] e [5,6,7]

Precisa gerar:

[123] e [567]

[125] e [367]

[126] e [537]

[127] e [563]

[135] e [267]

[136] e [267]

[137] e [256]

[156] e [237]

[157] e [236]

[167] e [235]

A partir disso **o que eu consegui até agora** é fazer uma permutação entre o mesmo vetor recursivamente.

Passando um vetor [1,2,3]. Gera a reposta:
123
132
213
231
321
312

Fica o código abaixo:

```
public void permutar(int[] num, int idx) {
    for (int i = idx; i < num.length; i++) {
        swap(num, i, idx);
        permutar(num, idx + 1);
        swap(num, i, idx);
    }
    if (idx == num.length - 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(num[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public void swap(int[] num, int a, int b) {
    int aux = num[a];
    num[a] = num[b];
    num[b] = aux;
}
```

**Alguém sabe como fazer a permutação entre os dois vetores?**

Comment: Oi Nicolas? `[1, 3, 2]` e `[5, 7, 6]` seria uma permutação válida ou só são validas permutações em que um membro do primeiro vetor é trocado com outro do segundo?

Comment: Apenas trocando o membros do primeiro pelo segundo.

Comment: Ok, segunda pergunta: `[5, 2, 3], [1,6,7]` é diferente de `[1,6,7], [5, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Não, já que os grupos tecnicamente seriam iguais.

Comment: Os números trocados precisam estar nas posições respectivas? Por exemplo, [7,6,3] e [5,1,2]  é uma permutação válida de [1,2,3] e [5,6,7]?

Comment: Sim, seria uma permutação válida, não importa a posição dos valores dentro de cada vetor

Comment: Bem interessante esse problema.  Última pergunta `[5, 2, 3], [1, 6, 7]` é diferente de `[2, 3, 5], [1, 6, 7]`?

Comment: Não, as posições dentro de cada vetor formam um grupo que não importa as suas posições dentro de cada grupo. A única coisa que importa é formar os diversos grupos diferentes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Preâmbulo

A resposta já vem tarde, mas talvez ajude alguém na mesma.

Segui o seu exemplo, e usei apenas arrays. Usando classes e objetos é possível limpar um bocado este código. Ao contrário da sua tentativa, esta implementação é **iterativa**, e, portanto, um pouco mais difícil de compreender.

### Implementação

Segue o método principal, que gera e imprime todas as permutações entre os dois vetores.

```
private static void permuta(int[] a, int[] b) {
    // p é o tamanho de cada permutação.
    // Começa por permutar um elemento de cada vez,
    // até os permutar todos (vetores originais).
    for (int p = 1, size = Math.min(a.length, b.length); p <= size; ++p) {
        // Listas de índices que vamos permutar em A e B nesta iteração.
        int[] indA = range(p);
        int[] indB = range(p);
        // Este sinal controla quando as permutações esgotam.
        boolean moveuTudo = false;
        while (!moveuTudo) {
            // Faz as permutações para os índices que temos.
            for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
                swap(a, b, indA[i], indB[i]);
            }
            imprime(a, b);
            // Volta a repor tudo no lugar para a próxima volta.
            for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
                swap(a, b, indA[i], indB[i]);
            }
            // Calcula os índices seguintes.
            moveuTudo = atualizaIndices(indB, b.length, p);
            if (moveuTudo) {
                indB = range(p);
                moveuTudo = atualizaIndices(indA, a.length, p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agora segue a parte mais difícil de entender neste algoritmo, imagino, que é como calcular os índices de permutações em cada iteração. Este método faz isso, e retorna `true` se já esgotou as possibilidades.

```
private static boolean atualizaIndices(int[] ind, int n, int p) {
    // Começa por mover o último índice.
    int k = ind.length - 1;
    boolean loop;
    boolean moveuTudo = false;
    do {
        loop = false;
        // Avança o índice.
        ind[k] = ind[k] + 1;
        if (ind[k] > n - (p - k)) {
            // Vai para o índice anterior, se o atual já vai
            // além do tamanho do vetor.
            --k;
            loop = k >= 0;
            moveuTudo = !loop;
        } else {
            // Coloca os índices seguintes à frente do atual.
            for (int k2 = k + 1; k2 < ind.length; ++k2) {
                ind[k2] = ind[k2 - 1] + 1;
            }
        }
    } while (loop);
    return moveuTudo;
}
```

Para compreender melhor como cheguei a este método, veja [esta imagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3ACombinations_without_repetition;_5_choose_3.svg) da Wikipedia, sobre combinações.

[image: algoritmo de combinações]

A ideia é igual à forma como estes quadrados vermelhos se *deslocam*. A diferença, é que neste caso temos **dois** conjuntos destes quadrados, estes índices, um em cada vetor. Chamei-lhes `indA` e `indB` no código.

Só quando o `indB` esgota os movimentos, é que `indA` vai para o segundo movimento, e `indB` volta ao primeiro estado. Isto refere-se a esta parte do código:

```
            // Calcula os índices seguintes.
            moveuTudo = atualizaIndices(indB, b.length, p);
            if (moveuTudo) {
                indB = range(p);
                moveuTudo = atualizaIndices(indA, a.length, p);
            }
```

Omiti os métodos `range`, `swap` e `imprime` para não alargar muito a resposta. O primeiro gera um array com números de 0 até `p`. O segundo troca elementos de dois arrays nas posições especificadas. O terceiro imprime para o ecrã. Nada demais, mas diga-me se quiser que os acrescente.

### Notas finais

Esta implementação gera permutações repetidas, se houver elementos repetidos entre os dois vetores. Se isso for um problema, penso que é mais fácil se implementar as permutações como classes suas, comparáveis, ou usando os conjuntos do java, de modo a que no fim as insira todas num conjunto de permutações (eliminando repetições automaticamente).

Para ver melhor como isto funciona, aprecie um exemplo com os vetores `[1,2,3]` e `[0,0,0]`. A escolha dos zeros é para ser mais fácil distinguir os movimentos que acontecem do primeiro vetor para o segundo. Aprecie como se movem da mesma forma que aqueles quadrados vermelhos.

```
[0, 2, 3] [1, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 3] [0, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 3] [0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 3] [2, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 3] [0, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 3] [0, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 0] [3, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0] [0, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 0] [0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 3] [1, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 3] [1, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3] [0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0] [1, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 0] [1, 0, 3]
[0, 2, 0] [0, 1, 3]
[1, 0, 0] [2, 3, 0]
[1, 0, 0] [2, 0, 3]
[1, 0, 0] [0, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 0] [1, 2, 3]
```